# Oracle SQL -- "not in" missing some rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, notin

I have a very simple query to find some values that are in one table, but not another.

```
select * from my_table were my_value in
   ('one','two','hello','blue')
and my_value not in
   (select my_value from my_table_2)
```

This returns two rows -- the rows of my_table with 'one' and 'two'.

But, then I ran this:

```
select * from my_table_2 where my_value in ('one','two')
```

and was shocked to discover that this returned two rows in my_table_2, with values of 'one' and 'two.'

The "not in" is getting 99% of the right things, but randomly missing a few values. What is the cause of this?

EDIT: Sorry, typo. Fixed it.

Comment: That top query isn't valid (`and not in()`). What was the real query?

Comment: `where value in ('one','two')` should *only* return rows with `one` or `two` - Can you show the *actual* queries you're using?

Comment: Stuff doesn't "randomly miss". Can you reproduce this? Are you sure `table_2` didn't change between your two queries?

Comment: @Mat I think that reproducing is probably impossible because I'm working with a lot of data and don't know the root cause, but other people are using entirely different session with no inserts/updates in between running these two and getting the same result as me.

Comment: "Exists" is logically equivalent to "In", but "Not Exists" is NOT equivalent to "Not In" if the inlist contains nulls. You will need something like ... myvalue not in (select blah from table2 where blah IS NOT NULL)

Answer (score 7):

My bet is that my_table2 contains NULL values in the my_value column.
NOT IN doesn't work as you might expect if your column contains NULL values, see [Techrepublic article on EXISTS / IN and NULL values](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-how-nulls-affect-in-and-exists/5319615)

I'd use NOT EXISTS in that case, should work as expected.

Comment: +1, *never* use NOT IN, use NOT EXISTS instead, you will save some headaches

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this issue was the difference in column types between the two tables.

my_table was using varchar2(10), but my_table_2 was using char(10). As a result, my_table_2 is actually returning what's in my_table_1, plus some spaces. Interestingly, even though 'apple', for example, would be 'apple     ', select my_value from my_table_2 where my_value = 'apple' does return the row.

Comment: ANSI trailing space handling.  Have a look at this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end

Comment: Tom Kytes recommends using `varchar2` always, and not ever using  `char`. http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1542606219593#14061634544400

Comment: @ShannonSeverance I don't see any logic in there about why you shouldn't use char. Using a char(x) can be seen as a constraint to ensure that your value is the exact right number of digits, and it's also very explicit about what's expected -- is there something flawed about that argument?

Comment: Well, consider what happened in your case. You look at the value in two tables and see the same value, "apple". However in the `char(10)` you actually have "apple␣␣␣␣" and in the `varchar(10)` field you have "apple". Sometimes things are padded, such as the values in the where clause of your second query, sometimes not. Much headache is avoided if one uses `varchar2()` and trims spaces on input. As to needing a column with a specific length, I prefer using `varchar2()` with a check constraint like so `columnName varchar2(10) constraint tableName_ck0 check (columnName = 10)`